# How would I figure out the frequency with which a recording of vibrato oscillates?

Tags: python, audio-processing, time-frequency

I'm not sure what the correct signal processing tool for this task is. My file is in m4a format. I'm comfortable using Python (arbitrary library(ies)) or MATLAB, but don't need code, just advice on an approach.

Possible ways to do this that I've thought about:

- high pass filter so that only the upper frequency of the vibrato shows up and then just ... count the peaks (this seems very intolerant to inconsistencies)
- something something wavelet transform so that I can keep rough time-frequency data and then see how many times frequency jumps above a certain threshold within a certain period
- normalize the data to the lowest frequency present (more robust than the high pass filter approach, but should accomplish the same thing)

Comment: I have found this. Can't seem to close the question myself. sorry! https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45095/measuring-vibrato-rate-of-a-sung-note